# Cycles vs Internal for a small animated outdoor scene?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation

What are the pros and cons for using cycles to render an outdoor scene?

**Note:** I have access to a Nvida GTX 670, so I can use CUDA to speed up the cycles rendering.

Comment: This is easy. **Blender Internal:** quick rendering. **Cycles:** more accurate, making it easier to achieve photo realism. I leave the task of a detailed answer to someone more knowledgeable than I.

Comment: @NathanOsman BI is quicker by default, but once you start enabling things to make it look more realistic (AO, environment lighting, indirect lighting, etc.) in my experience it ends up slower than cycles (which is actually designed for animations).

Comment: Related: [How is Cycles different from Blender Internal?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5820/599)

Comment: CVed as a concrete answer just depends on too many factors (what kind of look you are going for, the exact nature of the scene, the complexity of the scene, etc. etc.)