# How can I change the number of Samples in Blender Render in 2.70?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

How can I change the number of Samples in Blender Render in 2.70? I've looked everywhere in the UI, the internet and the manual and can't find it anywhere. [This page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Integrator) in the manual makes it look like it should be very obviously found in the Scene tab, but I still don't see it.

Comment: It turns out the information is found in the Blender Manual under [Render Settings](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render#The_Render_Settings_Panel). (Thanks to *Gandalf3* for this too)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That page is for cycles (note the URL: `/Render/`**`Cycles`**`/Integrator`).
"Scene settings" in that case refers to settings that effect the entire scene, as opposed to material settings which only affect objects which use that material.

There really isn't a global samples value for BI the way there is for cycles, as the way they work is so different (see [How is Cycles different from Blender Internal?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5820/599)). However, BI does use [raytracing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_%28graphics%29), similar to cycles, for some things. So where applicable there are *sample* settings to control the number of raytraced samples:

## Global ("scene") settings:

When the Gather method is set to *raytrace*, you can set the number of samples used for AO and environment lighting in *Properties > World > Gather > Sampling*:

[image]

## Per material/lamp settings:

- Glossy reflection and refraction in *Properties > Materials*:

  [image]
- Raytraced shadows on lamps:

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Render settings -> sampling -> Render samples. (The higher the number the more samples it will take to render each pixel, increasing rendering time and reducing common noise caused by cycles render)
(J. Bolaños)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I figured it out.

First off make sure you are in Cycles Render, not Blender Render, that will add several more options, it also is much better than Blender Render.

Comment: Hi, welcome. This question is very old (6 years) and already has an accepted answer suggesting to use Cycles. How is your late answer adding something useful here? If it does, please detail it a bit more to let others undesrtand...