# Textures disappear when the rendering engine is switched to cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

So in my graduation from blender internal to cycles, I've been experiencing numerous problems.
Now please bear with me, the answer is probably obvious but I'm new so cut me some slack.

This is how the model looks like in blender internal: 
[image: Looks good so far.]

Now I transfer to cycles:

[image]

[image]

And I get this result:
[image]

The textures are there in the menu bar, but they will not show up no matter what I try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Materials and textures work differently in cycles.

In BI, textures for the selected material are defined separately and most often in the properties editor.
In Cycles, textures are defined as part of the material itself and usually in the node editor (see [Learning cycles material nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/16486/599)).

Assuming a typical basic setup (one UV map, one texture, one material), then in cycles it should look something like this:

[image]

1. Make sure you are in the [node editor](http://blender.org/manual/editors/node_editor/introduction.html)
2. Make sure you are editing [*Material nodes*](http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/materials/index.html)
3. Add an [image texture](http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/textures.html#image-texture) node (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Textures > Image*) and select your image.
4. The materials section of the properties editor will reflect what you do in the node editor. Editing the material in either the node editor or the properties editor will update the other.

---

If you have lots of materials you might try an automated conversion script, see [How do I convert materials from Blender Internal to Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/364/599)