# Without using nodes, how can random materials be assigned to a set of objects?

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials, workflow, add-on

I was intrigued by this photo from Wikimedia commons

[image]

and inspired to create this similar structure

[image: Front and back views of chapel]

in  Blender. Each brick in my model is a separate mesh, and in many cases, they are separate objects as well. I'm working on a means of using a model such as this one to create masonry textures like this one

[image]

that are not found in the usual texture repositories. To make the texture more realistic, I'd like to create a set of materials, in this case, brick hues, and have an automated method to randomly assign a different one of the elements in the set of materials to each successive mesh. Is there such a tool available, or do I have to do this manually for each of the 1000 or so meshes?

Comment: The *random* output of the object info node will give you a random value per-object. If you plug it into a colorramp you can easily customize it to a set of picked colors

Comment: Except that I specifically asked "without using nodes....", although I understand that in the absence of other factors, I may have to deal with nodes....

Comment: Ah, my bad. May I ask why you want to avoid using nodes? (you [can set this up in the properties editor](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/16486/599) if it makes any difference)

Comment: No particularly good reason. My use of Blender is primarily in support of a game which employs user created content, but has it's own game and rendering engine, so I've not yet taken the time to build a skillset using nodes. So if there' a way to avoid nodes at the moment, my preference is to take it.

Comment: Perhaps [object color](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8319/599) or [vertex colors](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35868/599) might be of interest

Comment: You could also try a textured texture paint brush. It is kind of far-fetched.

Comment: I wrote an addon a while ago that distributes materials randomly between objects, islands or vertex groups. Could help you there: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgIUrZ8S1_Q

https://github.com/Tlousky/blender_scripts/blob/master/random_material_assigners/random_material_assigner_per_face_new_features.py

Comment: @Tamir, if you want to add the information about the object assigner, and change your comment to an answer, I'll accept it. Between the two items, they are exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: A possible workaround could be to make a small random selection, extend to linked and assign one material to the slected faces, then repeat the process for each material. Obiuvsly it would be faster if you would be able to join all the brick in one mesh.