# Weird shapes appearing on smoothed object

Tags: modeling

[image]

Hello,
It is me again. I am having an issue when I try to smooth my cat, as you can see on the picture, weird shadings appear at the corner of the eyes. It is also showing up when I am adding subdivision to my object, edges are getting more pitched, I don't understand why. Do you have any idea? [image]

Comment: It looks like overlapping faces which as a result are shown as poorly shaded. It could be due to doubles in the mesh as geometry looks like simple and clean. Select all (at least in eyes area) and remove doubles (in 2.8 it seems it's Merge > By Distance)

Comment: maybe also normal that are flipped? In that case just select all in Edit mode and shift N to recalculate

Comment: Normals were flipped! I followed your indication in edit mode and it worked! What is exactly a flipped normal? How does it happen?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43462/why-do-normals-exist and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker

Comment: Thank you very much!