# Why does my control panel not stay the same?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, interface

My material panel doesn't look like this when in cycles render mode [image]

I would like it to look like this in Cycles mode because here im in Blender render but instead it looks like this[image]

Is there a way to do this? I am trying to make the plane a shadow catcher to it should be invisible but i can't do that in this control panel. Please tell me how i can fix this or switch control panels

Comment: Materials in Cycles and Blender internal are completely different and not interchangeable. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20825/how-does-blender-internal-work/20829#20829 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60486/cycles-vs-internal-vs-game-engine/60504#60504

Comment: To create shadow catcher materials in cycles: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-to-make-a-model-cast-shadows-onto-the-world-texture-background/26686#26686 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19765/cycles-shadeless-shadow-catcher-material-for-rendering-onto-footage and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70230/transparent-shadow-catcher-under-hdri-lighting-in-cycles

Comment: cegaton is there any way like skype or email i can personally contact you? please i need serious help

Comment: use the chat rooms https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34814/the-rabbit-hole

Answer (score 2):

What you need is not possible.

Some of the Panels in the Properties Editor are dependent on the render engine.

Blender Render Engine has different shading philosophy and thus the settings appear differently.

You must choose a render engine for a project and go with it.