# I can't add a texture to my models

Tags: texturing, node-editor, edit-mode

I'm trying to add a texture to my model. I'm following some tutorials om YT to know how to do it, But my blender doesn't do what it should do.

I can't add the correct things in the node editor:

This is what my node editor displays by default:
[image]

This is what it should display by default:
[image]

Also I can't add a image texture box in my node editor.

I hope someone can help me out on this. :)

Comment: At the top of the screen, it says Blender Render. Click on it to open a dropdown menu and select Cycles Render. Cycles is what you are looking for and utilizes nodes. Blender Render does not.

Comment: Oh that was such a small thing. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Blender Internal does use nodes, however Cycles and Internal are just completely different. See [how they are different](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal)

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because you are in Blender Internal,
try switching to Cycles.

Comment: Please add detail to your answer, explaining how to do that. Like, an image and/or text.