# when you first import a character, are the materials still there even when in cycle render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, import

[image]

I just want to know, because I'm still getting use to this, but when you import a new character with eyes,hair etc. are the material still there in cycles render mode? or do I have to use node and set them up again?

This is how he is Blender render mode, but in cycles render, i only got the skin to show while the eyes and hairs where white. so do you have to find each png or file for those part or can I enable them someway on again?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cycles an Blender internal work with different material system,means your material in cycles wont work in internal.

There have been some Idea about converting the materials from and to the render engines,like:

- [Cycles material converter](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Material/Blender_Cycles_Materials_Converter)
- [Convert materials to Cycles](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/System/Convert_Materials_to_Cycles)

Comment: so if I switch between blender and cycles? they will show still?

Comment: @Ashton if you used one of these addons it will (in most of the cases).

Comment: i can't find materials_cycles_converter? what should i do

Comment: @Ashton you can find it in the material panel.