# Render image omitting unimportant polys

Tags: modeling, rendering

I have a model of an apartment, complete with furniture and all (and floor and ceiling) and I want to have a view of all rooms.

But if I move the camera above the model, far enough to encompass all within the frame, all I'll get is a plane (the ceiling seen from above). Of course that's not what I want.

Also, if I clip the render on an invisible plane (say midway the walls), many important elements are gone (like crown molding).

If I clip just under the ceiling, some small rooms (washbasins for example) get barely visible (in this particular case some of the walls should also go away, along with decoration it may have).

I'd like to know if there is a way to mark some meshes (or individual faces) as important, so they are not clipped away.

Like this: https://sketchfab.com/models/406b599627284efb967cc4084b0a25ee

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59070/striped-sphere-hide-backfaces/59073#59073 Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70576/transparency-masking-see-through-an-outer-sphere-and-see-inner-sphere-in-true/70619#70619 for cycles

Comment: Thanks @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, now I know that part of my answer is "backface culling". Given this new knowledge I was able to find https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6Qcvi2sNIg, which I think will be very useful to my case. I'll try it together with some clipping. Thanks.