# how to make camera look through objects from only one side?

Tags: camera

I have modeled a rather small room, and when trying to get the right camera angles I can't fit the camera inside the room without getting too close, so I wan't the walls and ceiling only to be visible if the camera is placed inside the room. Understand?

Make it so the camera can look through the ceiling and walls from the outside, but they still appear in the cameras view when the camera is on the inside looking out?

Comment: See the technique described here for a viewport-only effect https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70576/transparency-masking-see-through-an-outer-sphere-and-see-inner-sphere-in-true/70619#70619 For Blender internal use https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59070/striped-sphere-hide-backfaces/59073#59073

Answer (score 1):

### Final result:

This is kinda same idea as @Duarte Farrajota Ramos but it is working in Cycles (viewport/camera).

[image: final]

### Mesh:

Your mesh normals should point to the inside of the room as in the image below.

[image]

### Materials:

You will need to [assign different materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh) for floor and walls and ceiling.

[image]

**Floor material.** Could be anything you want.

**Wall and ceiling material.** Should look like this and in the place of red Diffuse you can and anything you want. Remember to check if Transparent shader color is pure white. Hex value #FFFFFF.

[image]

Comment: this solution worked, however the see through walls and ceiling now emits light? why is that and how can one fix such an issue? i've turned off all other light sources, and the room still looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/OSnm3

Comment: @jorba it is looking pretty strange and it's hard to tell just from the image. Could you upload you file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ or just problematic part of it?

Comment: I posted a new thread about this, as it was happening all over my project. here's the link for the new one https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98463/why-does-objects-appear-to-be-emitting-light

Comment: I know this is an old post, but you can also do this by adjusting the clipping in the camera settings.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found that actually worked was, scroll down in material properties, and check Backface culling.

[image: Backface culling option]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this is I guess the same as another answer.  Anyway, here goes:

Use the "Backfacing" output of the "Geometry" node as the mix factor between your shader (whatever it is) and a transparent shader.

[image: node layout for material with transparent front faces]

No matter what direction you are looking from, anything with front-facing normals will be transparent.  (As you can see from the picture, suzanne and a point lamp are inside a solid sphere, but in the rendered view you can see everything inside the sphere plus the back wall of the sphere.)

Note, however, that in an enclosed space all of your illumination is going to have to come from inside, and/or windows/openings!