# why do objects appear to be emitting light?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, lighting

It looks like the *bed to the right*, the *pane beneath the window* and *beneath the couch* are emitting light? why? all light sources except a moon outside is turned off.

All of these materials are basic Diffuse BSDFs. the wall with the window in it has a JPEG-texture wrapped on it.

i'm working in **Cycles Render** btw

[image]

Edit: heres the whole shebang with the layout of it all. the sun and the moon are the dots on the very right. the room where the "human" is sleeping on the couch is to the left. everything outside the room is just scenery, so that's why it looks very sloppy.

[image]

the "human guy" in pic 1 has nodes like this:

[image]

I have btw tried turning of all the light sources in the Outliner window, does that render light anyway somehow?

uploaded the .blend if anyone is interested 
[image]

Comment: please post a screenshot of the nodes for the guy object.

Comment: An [emission shader](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/emission.html#emission-node) creates a light source, therefore the object will emit light in your scene. Use a different shader(s) if that is not the desired shading for the object.

Comment: @Timaroberts but the light is there even if i turn off the emission for the guy, so it's not coming from the object screenshoted above

Comment: sorry, didn't know that was possible. revised that and put it where the old one was in the question @cegaton

Comment: Even when you have all of the lights off, the color for the world will still light the scene. To asses your lights correctly have the world be totally black

Comment: The light is coming from a source called sol kin, that is disabled in the viewport but enabled for rendering. What I don't understand is why that light is going through the wall, floor and grassy field.

Answer (score 1):

Mystery solved.  You have a lamp object called "sol kon" whose viewport visibility was turned off, but the render was left on.  That's what the light is coming from when you render.