# Fade in out layers in cycles blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation

I need to do an animation and I have issue to fade in object because I use mix shader on material but unfortunately, when the objects fade in, I see the faces on the backside of the object due to the transparency I think.
I have tried to put the object in layer and fade in the layer but the object is always visible (no fade in effect).
Do anyone know the node graph to achieve the fade in of the layer?

Comment: Either do it in post production through he compositor by animating the opacity of a separate render layer, which is probably a whole lot easier and computationally cheaper. Or make a [shader that masks backfaces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59070/striped-sphere-hide-backfaces/59073#59073) and makes them invisible.

Comment: When you say "fade in the layer" are you talking about render layers?  If you are using an Alpha Over node in the compositor to overlay your object on your bg, you can simply animate the "Factor" value of the Alpha Over node using keyframes.  This does require you to set up (at least) two render layers, one for your object and one for your background, and to check "Transparent" under "Film" in the Render tab.