# How to Render with Frontface Culling

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I flipped the normals, so that I could see the meshes layered within the outer mesh by using blackface culling. Reversing the normals made it so that instead of culling the backfaces, it culls the frontfaces. I did this, following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5edojx6DFI
[I modified the center to suit the aesthetic style I was going for. However, he doesn't go over rendering in the video. I'm using Blender Render.

I want my render to look something like this.
[image]

But I can only render it to look like this.
[image]

Is there anything I can do to salvage this?

Below is the Blender file for download:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Striped Sphere - hide backfaces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59070/striped-sphere-hide-backfaces)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Unless I missed something, that node set up did not work for me. I reversed the normals back to the original normals to ensure that it is culling the backface and not the frontface as well.

Comment: Make sure transparency is turned on in the *Render Pipeline* options

Comment: Is that in the render tab in the properties window or somewhere else?

Comment: I figured it out.... I found a means to make it work with the node editor. I'll post the answer after I'm done rendering.

Answer (score 3):

Applying this node set up (in Blender Render) will cull frontfaces. Apply your texture in the texture box onto the material you want to use. Linking it with color. Set the material to color output. Add a geometry node and set that to alpha. You need to set this to anything that has a mesh within it. But you will not need this setup for the most center mesh. For the most center mesh you can just apply whatever material/texture you want as typical with or without the nodes.

[image]

[image]