# Frontface Culling Not Rendering (even with nodes)

Tags: rendering, node-editor

Does just fine in everything else BUT Rendering - when in render, it just renders as if the culled frontface cuts through everything else behind it instead of showing it at all. Putting the viewport inside the object shows the inside, but that's it. Yes, I did the front/back node thing. Blender 2.79, computer apparently refuses to handle later versions

[image: Material view outside of affected object. Shows paper texture just fine.]

[image: Rendered view outside of object. Shows grey background of UI even through the torus behind it.]

[image: Rendered view inside of object. Shows the texture. Note how the light doesn't reach the cube.]

Someone said 'Make sure transparency is turned on in the Render Pipeline options'. ...where...

[image: Node display.]

Comment: I don't know 2.79 but possibly https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114524/how-to-render-with-frontface-culling will help?

Comment: @JohnEason the 'Make sure transparency is turned on in the Render Pipeline options' is quoted from there, yeah, the whole thing about this is that Rendering's NOT doing what the other thread's doing, even when using the same methods.

Comment: Sorry. No idea in that case.

Comment: @JohnEason Fair enough. I think it's just a 'this computer' thing.

Comment: ...i should really be doing this on the computer that actually supports the most updated version of blender... nuts.

Comment: Damn, haven't seen 2.79 in a while, cudos for the vintage version. Actually made me go fetch my old 2.79 setup for this. Seems to be working as  intended here. Did you actually invert the normals of the outer mesh?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yeah, did so on Mesh -> Invert Normals in Edit.