# Cycle Render - Black and White Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I can't figure out why Cycle Render is rendering only in Black and White even if I add more lights.

Blender Render is rendering okay.

Thanks, 
Manolo
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make materials in blender internal and expect them to work on Cycles. Each render engine works differently and the materials created for each one are not interchangeable. If you are going to render using cycles you need to create new materials.

Read:

[How is Cycles different from Blender Internal?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal)

[Cycles vs internal vs game engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60486/cycles-vs-internal-vs-game-engine)