# How to remove black box from my cloud, cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

First I create my cloud via metaball -> converting it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>-> pressing generate cloud.

Rendering is ok (it doesn't have this black bounding box), but after some time or some manipulations this black bounding box shows up.

However if I copy everything to new file it's ok again. Can it be something to do with way of creating sky?

Any suggestions?

You can check blend file:
https://yadi.sk/d/BZkRwk6T3DqUda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your max transparent bounces setting is set to 0 in *Properties > Render settings > Light Paths*:

[image]

This setting limits the number of transparent surfaces a [ray](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5821/599) is allowed to pass through. Setting this to 0 means rays are not allowed to pass through *any* transparent surfaces, rendering black instead.

Set this to something greater than 0 (e.g. 8) and all should work as expected.

Comment: wow. that was so simple, thank you very much!