# Png Textures Showing Black Mask when overlapping with other png textures

Tags: texturing

recently i've been wanting to sculpt a bird, so my first move was testing out feathers and noding them up. Everything was going great, the transparency was working the textures were working but when i started to use hair particle system, i saw that the png files masks where starting to show. After this i started to stack up 16 png textures and they even started to show the png mask. I dont know if there are anyways to fix this but if there is i would be thankful!
Problematic Picture:
[image]
Node Setup for Texture:
[image]

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73436/how-to-remove-black-box-from-my-cloud-cycles/73438#73438