# Why won’t my clouds from blender cloud generator work?

Tags: rendering, add-on

[image: Render]

I’ve been trying to make lots of clouds with the explosion type of blender cloud generator, it appears in chunks when I render. Does anyone know what to do? Thanks.

(Edit: I found out that it comes from to cloudbounds overlapping. So the question is now how to fix that.)

Comment: can you post a link to the cloud generator? and have you checked the add-ons documentation?

Comment: The add on is integrated into blender. There’s no documentation.

Comment: I think you need to increase your [transparency bounces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73438/935).

Comment: cool! never seen that there before. https://en.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Cloud_Gen
I did try it out and did not get the same issue when rendering unless lowering the number of Transparency Bounces as per @sambler