# Why is my object rendering correctly in blender render and not in cycles?

Tags: rendering, image

Ok I'll make this simple:

Cycles render:
[image: Cycles]
Blender render:
[image: Blender]
How do I make them both show up?
Thanks!

Comment: Cycles an blender internal are not interchangeable, they use different ways to create materials. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal

Answer (score 1):

Cycles render and blender render use different types of materials, to "transform" a blender material to a cycles material there is the button "use nodes" in the materials tab:

[image]

By the way, this may result in a model with no texture so you will probably have to apply the texture in cycles.