# Why does the material tab has a different layout?

Tags: materials

I downloaded a Blend from Blend Swap and the materials are behaving much differently than I am used to - I think it has something to do with Cycles maybe? Here is what I see:

[image]

On the left is my "normal" materials tab, and the right is from Blend Swap. What is going on here? Why are they different? Also, with the screen on the right I cannot assign a different material to different parts of the mesh:

[image]

Any ideas what I'm into here?

Comment: You need to change the render engine to blender internal (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTAo2.png) and recreate the materials. Materials are not interchangeable between cycles and blender internal.

Comment: Related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is a Cycles render file, and the materials look like that since they mention 'Diffuse' etc. Your faces must be selected to use the assignment button, but in this particular file they might already be assigned but the material might not be set to use a color for the viewport....