# Downloaded Materials not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, import, blend-files, append

When I download this [LOMAR TOON MATLIB](https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/80561)
I open my project and go to file -> append and select the material I want to append. However, after doing so the material renders fine on the right in the preview pane. When I view the object in object mode it is just the base color, none of the texture of the material is present. I have done it a bunch of different times following different suggestions I have found here on stackexchange but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?
Oh and I am running blender 2.78

Comment: you have a tag in your question for cycles, the file you linked to in blendswap is for blender internal. Materials are not interchangeable between those render engines. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal