# Cycles won't render image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image

However, blender render does render the plane image. It's just a picture of trees (and an added sun, pointing at the plane, and I made a two second animation, just to see (I'm like really new, still).
So, I decided to try cycles render, to see if there was any difference in the image (and to see how much longer it takes), and it just renders the plane without the image.
I added an icosphere, just to see and both renders it.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is Cycles different from Blender Internal?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal)

Comment: Switching to cycles requires you to re-do all of your materials and lighting. Materials are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have texture created with "Node Editor".  This is the basic node for texturing in Cycles Render.
[image: Basic Texturing in Cycles Render]

From 3D View, toggle to Node Editor -- make sure to toggle "Use Nodes"
[image: Toggle Node Editor view]