# Rendering flat faces shows too many tris!

Tags: modeling, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, light

I am rendering out images of some low-poly cars I am working on. I am having difficulty with making the quads look as good in the render as they do in the scene view...in the below pic the scene view is on the left and render on the right. Any suggestions? Is this just a matter of modelling/flattening each face or is there a way to tweak this in the render?

[image]

Comment: Based on the provided image it looks like the internal render, and not cycles.

Comment: Internal render? You mean, inside of Blender? Yeah, that's what I'm using. Just wondering if there is a way to avoid triangulating faces on render?

Comment: We have two render engines inside blender, cycles and internal. Both of them are actually internal to the program. I ask because normally we tag questions as either cycles or internal so people know what engine to answer for. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal for an explanation on the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah found the answer:

"Set smooth shading and add an edge-split modifier with the Edge Angle set to 0 degrees"

https://blenderartists.org/t/making-mesh-render-faces-as-quads-not-triangles-in-sculpt-mode/518770/7

Comment: not 'the answer', but rather, just a way around it