# Cant find attribute node

Tags: vertex-colors

Complete and utter noob to 3d traditional 3d modeling, let alone blender.

I was going to learn how to do lighting, but the imported colours are considered vertex colors, and cannot be rendered without fiddling with nodes. All the guides tell me to put in an "attribute node" but it's not there.

[image]

The space where it is, above Geometry is filled by Fresnel. So im extremely confused on how im suppose to do this if theres mno way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **Blender Render**.

To be able to use **Attribute** node you will need to switch to **Cycles Render**.

[image: cycles]

Here are differences between them: [How is Cycles different from Blender Internal?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal)

Comment: In Blender Render, you can also use the vertex color as an input, but with the Geometry node (http://builder.openhmd.net/blender-hmd-viewport-temp/render/blender_render/materials/nodes/types/input/geometry.html)

Comment: @thibsert yep, that is correct, but question is about Attribute node. If OP is following Cycles tutorials, using Vertex Colors in Blender Render will be no help at a long stretch. I suppose ;)