# The interface for material looks different than the one on tutorial

Tags: texturing, materials

I am a complete beginner and following a tutorial about how to put a texture on a cube. I think maybe they have a different version of Blender because what I see in a few places is different so it is very hard to follow.

In the video after UV unwrapping the cube they click to create a new material then click this little button next to the colour and then get a menu where they can choose 'Image texture'

[image: Image texture button]

But in my Blender which is 2.79b when I click **Add material** it looks like this:

[image: New material in Blender 2.9]

As you can see it is totally different and I can't find anywhere a Color box with a button like in the video. I can't even see 'Surface' anywhere. So I am stuck.

- Did they change Blender so much I need to find a new tutorial for my version?
- Is there a simple way to do the same thing in the version I have?

Comment: See for differences between the render engines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal

Comment: @MrZak Maybe to someone experienced it is the same but not from my perspective seeing as I don't know what BSDF is. Thanks.

Comment: BSDF in short stands for shader. There's nothing wrong if question is marked as duplicate. This is how this site works. Reason for vote is that this question was already asked before and already recieved an answer

Comment: Hi. Please consider the size of images you upload in future. These are very large images for the information they are showing.

Comment: @RayMairlot They are actual size screenshots. I should have scaled them down as I realised after posting the question that this website shows them at 72dpi instead of how they look on my screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found a comment about something called Cycles mode. I don’t know why but apparently you have to switch it to **Cycles Render**.

There is a menu at the very top of the window. This was not explained in the video. I would love to know more about why it's different or what this means!

[image]

Comment: In your version of Blender, and using the Blender renderer,  you have a Diffuse channel. If you click on the colour field next to Diffuse, you can change the colour.

If you want to add an image etc, you click on the next icon along in the Properties editor, the one that looks like a chess board.

Comment: It means the rendering engine. Like an *oven* and *fried pan*, you can choose what you want your scene object been cooked.