# Cycles Not Rendering Specified Samples

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image][image]I set my render to sample 800 samples.

When I look in the corner while rendering it only says 510 and has LOTS of pixelation.

I've never had this problem before.

[image]

Comment: Oh, I am also using Cycles.

Comment: Is it possible you could you upload a screenshot of this?

Comment: Is there any more information you could include? Things like: Can you replicate this consistently? What have you tried?

Comment: Embed a screenshot by clicking the little image icon and selecting the file path.

Comment: @BinaryGreen Edit your question and click the little image icon above the editor.

Comment: Alright, embedded the picture. So it said something like 'Path Tracing Tile 510/510.'

Comment: Exactly, when you render by tiles, that is what it calls each one. Looks like it completed properly to me. Could you get a shot of while it is rendering?

Comment: No. I don't think we need one, why?

Comment: Everything I am seeing is telling me it is operating normally, can I see the render settings?

Comment: I just noticed something, your Light Paths max values are HUGE! I use up to 16 at most!

Comment: Oh, and another thing. I've rendered with this project before, same settings as these. Then I kind of rearranged all the objects. Used to be some sort of indoor garage.

Comment: I was wondering if that might be the case. You have too much light in the scene. The global light and whatever lamps you have are way too powerful.

Comment: Edit: Found out Strength was 200. Lowered to about 25. Still same results though.

Comment: So what is wrong with this, then?

Comment: Did you try editing the Light Paths values? I would drop them by a factor of 100 . ..

Comment: I dropped the bounces, glossy from 1024 to 500. Same result.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: !!! You have square samples enabled, so you are trying to render **640,000** samples! (640,000 = 800^2) You probably want to disable square samples in _Render Settings > Sampling_.

Answer (score 7):

You appear to have a per-renderlayer sample override limit set in *Properties > Render layers > Layer*:

[image]

To avoid this, either set the sample override to 0 in the appropriate renderlayers, or tell blender to ignore per-renderlayer sample overrides in *Properties > Render settings > Sampling*:

[image]

---

Note that you have [*Square Samples*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6135/599) enabled. This means that blender will use the number of samples you specified2. The total number of samples is displayed below:

[image]

*<sub>(TBH I don't really see the point of this feature..)</sub>*

Also 500 bounces are <s>almost</s> never needed. Higher numbers of bounces give diminishing returns, and I doubt there will be much visual difference between 6 bounces and 100 bounces in a fairly diffuse scene such as yours.

Comment: From your view, so for all the integrator (however you spell it) settings should be somewhere between 6 and 100? Like the transparency, etc?

Comment: I GOT IT! You're a natural! Thank you so much! What I think messed it up is first I made one layer with the car and a second with the land, and probably accidentally changed the settings as I moved all to one layer. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I started another project. It's not working again. I ignored layer samples, set scene to 1000, how do I fix this thing again?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise What is supposed to be different?

Comment: @BinaryGreen Huh.. Is it possible you could upload your .blend? It sounds like something weird is happening, and this would be the easiest way to find out what.