# Cycles render using incorrect sample amount

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

When going to render my scene, I have my samples set to 60 (A test render) and shadow layers with alpha set up. When I start to render the animation, it begins to render at 510 samples and the alpha layers don't work. Any ideas as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: Probably checking Render Layers tab, Layers scroll, Samples slider, may help. If not 0, It makes cycles to render adjacent layer using that amount of samples.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21154/599

Comment: There is a checkmark in the samples tab that says "square samples." I don't know if 16 squared is 510, but that is probably what is happening.

Comment: the samples are set to zero in the render layers tab and square samples are unchecked. I don't know what else could be the problem.

Comment: I just realized that the only thing wrong, is the displayed sample value. it seems that the actual sampling is correct. I still would like to figure out how to fix the display in the render view though. In addition I am trying to render out a shadow layer, which isn't working properly. I have a setup that is supposed to render out a shadow catcher layer, but is only renders out one big alpha image.