# Why is blender using so few resources

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, modifiers, image, shaders

Right now I am doing the final render on my light-saber and previously when I would render objects with around 1000-3000 samples depending on the complexity it would take maybe an hour but now blender says it will take 69 HOURS to render this light saber and only uses 2000 samples. My system hardware consists of a GTX 970, 16 GB of RAM and an Intel i7-4790k CPU running currently at 4.5 GHZ [image].I am just very confused why on the render it says that it is only using around 18.37mg of ram when I have 16 GIGABYTES. I've set blender to high priority in Windows Task Manager and im just confused on why its using so little resources and why is it taking so long to render everything. [image]

Comment: You have set it to render 4 million samples, as shown in the top right of that image...that's why it is going to take a while to finish.

Comment: Yes, also, a small scene only needs a small amount of memory, and using more will not speed the render process at all

Comment: A good render could be set to about 500 samples up to 2000..., above that the difference will not be that much, 4 Million samples will take forever even on double Nvidia Titan X!, check the settings you might have put the wrong digits ..

Comment: Possibly related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21154/599

Answer (score 1):

Fixing this should be a matter of setting the sampling back to 2000.  I think you accidentally put in 4,000,000 instead.  It is possible that you have "Square sampling" selected.

Comment: Although it could be set to 2000 samples but the squared samples may have been ticked which will lead to the 4M total.