# Render taking ages, just CPU or i did something wrong?

Tags: rendering

I'm an absolute beginner, i've installed blender just some days ago, but i got some basics from other software and my background.
So, my GPU seems too old, it's not that fast and sometimes crashes so i'm rendering on CPU got an i7 put to 6 thread so i can use the PC while it render (i mostly write code, so nothing intensive)... But the render is taking ages 
[image: Ages]
So i've read some articles on how to tweak to render faster, but the results aren't that good, the scene seems waaay darker and i loose lot of color from the environment, the scene is an interior, geometrically speaking easy. [image: Easy peasy]
But a nightmare in terms of lighting and textures, all the materials use the new shader and procedural textures...
Can i have some advice ? should i just turn down some settings?[image: Quite high btw]
How do i balance what i turn down ?

And at least... [image: Wroooom]
Why so noisy ? after 3 hours, more than 200 samples i was expecting something more... clear... at the original resolution is way more noisy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2000 samples **squared** will be 4 000 000 total samples do you need that many? Uncheck square samples.

[image]

Comment: Oh damn! i didn't noticed that, is that like the resolution multiplier, it just rise the number of samples ?

Comment: You squared the number of samples. (multiply 2000 x 2000). Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/how-does-squared-samples-make-tweaking-easier

Comment: Also updating the drivers i've managed to get the GPU to work, but seems that the i HAVE to turn down light bounces if i want to finish a render in a less than a few day

Comment: A piece of advise:  find out what the options are for and how to use them before you move the values...