# Overlaying images with different seed values

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Lets say I render 200 images with different seed values and 50 samples each. I wrote a program that adds all color values of each pixel and color together and then divides it by the amount of images.
So am I allowed to say, that the combined images has 10.000 samples?

Comment: Yes, almost. [This technique isn't *quite* as noiseless as rendering the equivalent number of samples at once](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7126/599).

Comment: So is there any formula, for how many samples it would be as a straight render?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2808/599. If I understand correctly, I think this would depend on the scene and how well samples are distributed. The stacking technique is more or less equivalent to straight Monte Carlo integration. The reason cycles does slightly better is because it uses Quasi-Monte Carlo integration, which tries to avoid duplicate samples. The increase in efficiency with Quasi-Monte Carlo integration is apparently difficult to calculate..

Comment: Ok... That seems quite complicated... Because I do not wanna say 10000 samples, if it equals for example only 5000 samples...

Comment: You can say that you approximate 10,000 samples by combining multiple images of less samples.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21806/how-to-combine-low-sample-renders

Comment: Thanks, but I already know how to combine them.. I wrote a nice program that does that for me ;-)